# Shifter cable broke in the shifter and now the end is stuck in the shifter

Tags: derailleur, shifter, shifting, cable

So The end of my rear derailleur shifter cable is stuck in the shifter. Is it even possible to get out? See the picture below. Shifting up and down doesn't really do anything to its position.

[image: close-up of cable end in shifter]

Edit: I got it a bit further. Seems like it only needs to shift up one more time before I can pull it out but is doesn't want to.

[image: Another close-up with the cable in a slightly different position]

Comment: Older brifter designs are notorious for chewing up shift cables.  If you feel shift quality deteriorate, then check the cable and change if needed before it breaks.  I've taken to changing the right hand cable every year, because it won't last two for me.

Comment: @Criggie it seems to be even more true of the 11sp shimano road groups

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take off the little plastic cover on the bottom of your 5800 shifter. The line of its edge is visible in your second photo (1 or 2 screws). You will then have good access to remove the head. You can also help the mechanism around if you need to with a pick or small screwdriver.

Comment: This video shows the process of extracting the cable. In his case, the cable was frayed but not completely broken, though the process is similar. I myself experienced a broken rear shift cable. The key thing is as Noise pointed out, is to peel back the hood enough so you can remove the screw and remove the small access panel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWDuQRXiGO4

Comment: This is how I eventually managed to get it out. I used a paperclip bent into a hook to pullthe mechanism and was then able to shift up enough for the damaged end to be removed.